# Python AWS - GetRawMessageContent from Sent Emails

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, email

How can I read the content of the mailbox in my workmail in AWS? I mean, read every single email I have in the mailbox.

I already can connect well to the base and send the mails, but I do not know how to continue to pick up mails and read the plain text of the mails already sent.

```
import base64
import email
import smtplib

s = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
s.starttls()
s.ehlo()

if SMTP_USE_TLS:
    s.starttls()  # Puts connection to SMTP server in TLS mode

s.ehlo()
s.login(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD)

>>> s
<smtplib.SMTP object
```

Comment: So you are essentially wanting to download your "sent" folder? Use IMAP: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/userguide/using_IMAP_client.html

Comment: Any already solved code that performs this task?

Comment: mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER)